# Windows Gradle build : Could not expand ZIP

Tags: java, gradle, apache-curator

I'm working on a MapReduce app and currently using Gradle to build the project. I'm using following dependencies and when I execute the `./gradlew clean build` I'm getting Could not expand ZIP error.

```
implementation 'org.apache.hive:hive-jdbc:3.1.3'
implementation 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:3.3.2'
implementation 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs:3.3.2'
```

Stacktrace

```
 Could not expand ZIP 'C:\Users\..\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.curator\apache-curator\2.12.0\b1ff6ce0741facb15217ae9254ee7167bc7b15e\apache-curator-2.12.0.pom'.


org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':jar'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:188)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:186)
```

I tried clearing out gradle cache `gradlew cleanBuildCache --refresh-dependencies`  that didn't workout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue. My goal was to create a fatjar and for that I have updated the gradle jar task to create a fat jar.

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "main.Main"
    }
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
}
```

The issue was, in the `C:\Users\..\.gradle\cache\..` folder there were some dependencies without a .jar file. In my case only a .pom file. So I removed the task and created a new task(customFatJar) only to get `.jar` files. That fixed the issue.

Fix:

```
task customFatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'main.Main'
    }
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.filter {
            it.name.endsWith('.jar')
        }
    }
    with jar
}
```